# JAVA server socket receiver receiving data only when the client socket program is stopped in python

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have written the a TCP socket program in python where the temperature readings will be sent to a particular IP and port . Here is the code for the client socket program in TCP.

```
  import time
    import os
    import fnmatch
    import logging
    import socket
    import json
    import sys
    from datetime import datetime

    logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/DS18B20_error.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
    HOST,PORT="10.10.1.114",8090
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST,PORT))
    def postReadingsUDP(id,temperature,currentTime):
            thermalId=str(id)
            temp=str(temperature)
            data={"sensorId":thermalId,"Temperature":temp,"Timestamp":currentTime}
            jsonObj=json.dumps(data)
            sock.send(jsonObj)


    def postTempReadings(IDs, temperature,currentTime):


        for i in range(0,len(temperature)):
            postReadingsUDP(IDs[i],temperature,currentTime)

    #get readings from sensors every 1 sec  and send them to server
    while True:

      temperature = []
      IDs = []

      for filename in os.listdir("/sys/bus/w1/devices"):
       if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '28-*'):
          with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + filename + "/w1_slave") as fileobj:
            lines = fileobj.readlines()
            if lines[0].find("YES"):
              pok = lines[1].find('=')
              temperature.append(float(lines[1][pok+1:pok+6])/1000)
              IDs.append(filename)
            else:
              logger.error("Error reading sensor with ID: %s" % (filename))

     if (len(temperature)>0):
            localtime=datetime.now()
            currentTime=str(localtime)
            postTempReadings(IDs,temperature,currentTime)
```

The server receiver code is in JAVA

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;




public class TcpServerSample {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
       String clientSentence;
       ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8090);

       while(true)
       {
          Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
          BufferedReader inFromClient =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
          clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
          System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence+"\n");
       }
    }
}
```

The problem iam facing is that i cannot receive any data from the client until i stop the client program , it seems the JSON data that was created when the client program was running kept on appending and was sent as a single json data to the server .

The data i expected is that json should be sent in continuosly like below

Received: {"sensorId": "28-041673cb78ff", "Temperature": "[22.75]", "Timestamp": "2016-11-23 10:36:41.038058"}

but the actual data was like all JSON data's were appended and sent as one data.

Received: {"sensorId": "28-041673cb78ff", "Temperature": "[22.75]", "Timestamp": "2016-11-23 10:36:41.038058"}Received: {"sensorId": "28-041673cb78ff", "Temperature": "[22.75]", "Timestamp": "2016-11-23 10:36:41.038058"}Received: {"sensorId": "28-041673cb78ff", "Temperature": "[22.75]", "Timestamp": "2016-11-23 10:36:41.038058"}

Comment: `How to detect EOS(End OF STREAM)` ? Some socket system using `*NULL*` but don't see any start-end delimiter. Short comment things `WELLCOME TO PROTOCOL WORLD !`

Comment: Your server need a `BUFFER SIZE` or a `END DELIMITER`(End delimiter is best things cos don't wait reaching buffer).

Comment: can you modify the code above and show me an example on where should i put the delimeter because it seems if i add "\n" by   jsonObj=json.dumps(data)+"\n" ,it's not working

Comment: will be work if add "\n" char python code but how to detect on server side ? Need check whole packet if last incoming element is `\n`. `getInputStream()` handle your incoming packet(and my opinion removed `\n` character ). Need reading `Byte mode` all incoming message(server side).

Comment: can u change the mentioned server and client source code so that i can understand it better?

Comment: got the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418326/get-data-from-client-in-server-socket-java